# How to force iPad/iPhone safari to use older version of webkit?

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, webkit, ios6

We have an iPad/iPhone enabled web application which was working good on iOS 5.1 and AppleWebKit/534.46 when i upgraded the iPad to iOS 6.0 and accordingly the safari webkit upgraded to AppleWebKit/536.26 many functions stopped and the layout got corrupted as we depending on absolute positioning extensively,so there are to ways to go, the first is to restructure the whole application to handle the webkit changes (this option will take a lot of rework),the second is to find a work around to force iPad safari to use the previous version of webkit (this one will take 0 time and i prefer it).

So, is there any way to force the iPad safari to use a specific webkit version to render the HTML???

thanks in advance,

Comment: Yes, have the user install the appropriate iOS version. While that is easier for you, likely your users will find it onerous. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

The only version of webkit on Mobile Safari is whatever one that exists in the iOS version the device has installed.